# Scale all fonts with css/js

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, scaling

I need to change the size of all fonts with one click (so it's adjusted for people with eyesight problems). After next click it should go back to normal. What's the easiest way to do so? I don't want to access every single text as there's a lot of them. I would like to scale all by approximately 20-50%. Is there an easy way to do so? I use bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a relative unit for font-size ie. rem or em. Use the same unit throughout the CSS. When you need to scale the size just increase the body's font-size. Other element's font-size will also increase due to relative units. Or how about increasing the zoom level of body using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Select all elements and scale their font-size by the amount that you want.

```
$("*").each(function(index) {
  var size = $( this ).css("font-size");
  $( this ).css("font-size", parseInt(size)*YOUR_FACTOR);
});
```

You can also reverse this by keeping a variable for toggling.

Comment: I like the simplicity, but I had to add parsing the font size. 24px*3 is NaN. But with parsing it works. It just crashes sometimes with long numbers eg 2.83333333 and I have to figure that out

Comment: I couldn't get you. Do you want to change all the font sizes into unique size or some factor of their current sizes?

Comment: into a factor, so that works, I just had to modify it

Comment: Have you figured it out or need further help?

Comment: Tutu Kaeen, you can use `parseInt()` method to avoid long and float numbers.

Comment: I have edited the code with `parseInt()`. Thank you @KhyatiAgolaChandak

Answer (score 1):

To select all element use `$( "*" )` and to set `font-size` use `.css( "font-size", "25px" )`

```js
var flag=true;
function changeSize(){
if(flag)
{
   $( "*" ).css( "font-size", "50px");
   flag=false;
   }
 else{
 
  $( "*" ).css( "font-size", "15px");
  flag=true;
  }
}
```

```css
*{
font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>DIV</div>
<span>SPAN</span>
<p>P</p>
<button onclick="changeSize()">change size</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this . You have to iterate over your `containter` on elements like `p ul` anything on which you want to increases font.

```js
$(".action-btn").on("click", function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var elements = $("#section").find("p, ul,ol");
        var fontSizeToIncreasedOrDecreased = 2;
        fontChange(elements,fontSizeToIncreasedOrDecreased,action)
    });
  
function fontChange(elements,fontSizeToIncreasedOrDecreased,action) {
    $(elements).each(function() {
        var c = $(this);
        if(action == 'in'){
        c.css("font-size", parseInt(c.css("font-size")) + fontSizeToIncreasedOrDecreased)
        }else{
        c.css("font-size", parseInt(c.css("font-size")) - fontSizeToIncreasedOrDecreased)
        
        
        }
        
        
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section">

  <P> Lorem ipsum text ... </p>
 <ul>
 <li>hello 1 </li>
 </ul>
<input type="button" class="action-btn" value="Zoom In" data-value="in" id="btn" />
<input type="button" class="action-btn" value="Zoom Out" data-value="out" id="zoomOut" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better you toggle the css classes on click in javascript.

For example

Html

```
<div class="original-font">
  <!-- any element-->
</div>
```

css

```
.original-font.large-font {
   font-size: calc('your original font' + '% how much you want to increase or decrease');
}
```

Js

```
$(".original-font").click(function() {
  $(".original-font").toggleClass('larger-font');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using zoom property:

```css
html,
body {
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeSize('up')">+ size (using zoom)</button>
<button onclick="changeSize('down')">- size(using zoom)</button>
<div>DIV</div>
<span>SPAN</span>
<p>P</p>

<script>
  function changeSize(param) {
    var zoom = 0.1
    if (param == "up") {
      $("body").css("zoom", '+=' + zoom);
    } else {
      $("body").css("zoom", '-=' + zoom);
    }
  }

</script>
```